# System.ArgumentException while updating Model from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Our Application is an MVC Application. We are using Entity Framework. When I am updating the model to add a table from the database. I am recieving an exception and it says

"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occured while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'An entry with the same key already exists'."

I am not able to figure out what is the problem. Can I have a solution to get over the problem.

Comment: please add a bit more details here. code samples, what table, how you are doing your update. The details here are a bit vague and it really depends 100% on your implementation.

Comment: The Designer class has a large set of tables and stroed procedures. I cannot be able to paste it over here. When I check the Model Browser I don't see that entity over there. Even though I add new table or new stored procedure it leads to the same error. I am just right clicking in the .edmx file and select Update Model from Database and selecting the new table and click finish.

Comment: I had the same problem when I created two foreign keys to the same table in my database, but forgot to rename the relationship from the default. Even though they weren't named exactly the same (FK_Foo_Bar, FK_Foo_Bar1).

Answer (score 41):

I had it just as you did. You probably have two identical nodes: `EntitySetMapping`. You should remove one and everything will be ok.

Comment: This was it for me!  I had an EDMX with a large number of EntitySetMapping's, so I ran a little `grep | sort | uniq -c` to find dupes.  Manually removing them from the file fixed the error.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue today. It means that you have two definitions of some sort with the same name. In my case, it was a duplicate EntitySetMapping. It happened as a result of me migrating some customizations from an old version of my model into a new version. I copied an EntitySetMapping with custom insert/delete/update mappings, but I didn't think to delete the mapping that had been previously auto-generated by the model designer.

Unfortunately, you won't know you have this problem until the next time you attempt to update from the database, meaning there's potential for this one to go undetected for some time.

In the future, when making significant changes to the model via the XML editor, I would recommend that you do a test database update just to make sure that all is well.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into a similar issue with EF6 where this error was occurring and there was no duplicate key anywhere... **That were visible in the edmx**. What I had to do was right-click in the edmx and select Model Browser. In the Model Browser view and under Model/Entity Types, some lingering entities were there. For some reason, deleting all the entities in the edmx actually didn't do what you would think. Removing these lingering Entities in the Model Browser solved my problem. Hopefully this will solve some people's problems because this type of solution is easy to fix but hard to find.

Comment: it's hard to find the duplicate key, and this solution is not work for my case. I just removed all entities in Model browser, and regenerate it from database. this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there is another table with the same key exists. Can we see the code? Read more on this exception [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx).

Comment: The Designer class has a large set of tables and stroed procedures. I cannot be able to paste it over here. When I check the Model Browser I don't see that entity over there. Even though I add new table or new stored procedure it leads to the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I figured out a fix for my case.

Step 1: I deleted the table from the edmx model that contained the reference or what ever that was causing the error.

Step 2: I right clicked the designer and click "Update Model from Database" again and all was fixed.

FYI, the only way I knew which table to delete was because it was the last one modified since the "Update Model from Database" worked last.

[Taken From Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/633a53aa-21be-43c0-bca6-c4f58ee30df8/entity-framework-erroran-entry-with-the-same-key-already-exists?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required)

Answer (score 0):

This is a more detailed answer based on [Tazos333's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11668896/2780791).

Finding the actual duplicate is the hardest part. Using Powershell it can be done by:

```
Get-Content .\models.edmx | Group-Object | Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

In order to get as few false positive results as possible, run this only for the `<!-- C-S mapping content -->` section (copy-pasted in other text file).

Besides scalar properties duplicates (quite normal, since tables might contain the same column names), the duplicate  `<EntitySetMapping Name="...">` will be very obvious.